# NFS server identical "badcalls" and "badauth" count

Tags: linux, nfs4

What are **badauth** and **badcalls** in nfsstat? I searched and could not find any description of "badauth".

We have an NFS server and just one NFS client on which exported partition is mounted read-only.  Both machines on same subnet. Both are Almalinux9.3

The NFS clients show high i/o wait states. I notice that the NFS server shows high **badcalls** and **badauth** counts. Also both are same number. How are they related? Below is the clipping of nfsstat command.

```
Server rpc stats:
calls      badcalls   badfmt     badauth    badclnt
784945     487053     0          487053     0
```

How to understand this and what is the cause?

I think I can confidently rule out network congestion (NICs are 25Gbps and exported filesystem is SSD)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The relationship is:

```
badcalls = (badfmt + badauth + badclnt)
```

`badauth` is incremented when either the SunRPC auth header is not valid (e.g. auth_gss Kerberos validation failed, bad sequence number, packet corrupt, etc) or the program refused the client, e.g. I *think* this is incremented when NFS did not find an /etc/exports entry for that client? (The kernel source code gets a bit confusing at this point).